# How to reverse the sort of a Groovy collection?

Tags: list, sorting, collections, groovy

I am sorting a list based on multiple fields.

```
sortedList.sort {[it.getAuthor(), it.getDate()]}
```

This works fine, but I want the date to be reversed and `reverse()` does not work.

**How do I sort the author in ascending order but sort the date in descending (reverse) order?**

Example of what I want:

```
Author    Date
Adam      12/29/2011
Adam      12/20/2011
Adam      10/10/2011
Ben       11/14/2011
Curt      10/17/2010
```

Example of what I have:

```
Author    Date
Adam      10/10/2011
Adam      12/20/2011
Adam      12/29/2011
Ben       11/14/2011
Curt      10/17/2010
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For multi-property sorts like this you'll get the most control if you use the `sort()` with a closure or a Comparator, e.g.:

```
sortedList.sort { a, b ->
    if (a.author == b.author) {
        // if the authors are the same, sort by date descending
        return b.date <=> a.date
    }

    // otherwise sort by authors ascending
    return a.author <=> b.author
}
```

Or a more concise version (courtesy of [Ted Naleid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8912/ted-naleid)):

```
sortedList.sort { a, b ->

    // a.author <=> b.author will result in a falsy zero value if equal,
    // causing the date comparison in the else of the elvis expression
    // to be returned

    a.author <=> b.author ?: b.date <=> a.date
}
```

---

I ran the above in groovysh on the following list:

```
[
    [author: 'abc', date: new Date() + 1],
    [author: 'abc', date: new Date()],
    [author: 'bcd', date: new Date()],
    [author: 'abc', date: new Date() - 10]
]
```

And received the correctly sorted:

```
[
    {author=abc, date=Fri Dec 30 14:38:38 CST 2011},
    {author=abc, date=Thu Dec 29 14:38:38 CST 2011},
    {author=abc, date=Mon Dec 19 14:38:38 CST 2011},
    {author=bcd, date=Thu Dec 29 14:38:38 CST 2011}
]
```

Comment: you can also shorten this up to a one liner (and skip an explicit if check) with:  sortedList.sort { a, b -> a.author <=> b.author ?: b.date <=> a.date }

Comment: @TedNaleid - Thanks for the tip; I had considered shortening it down, but decided to leave it for the sake of understandability. I'll put yours in there, though, for completeness.

Comment: @TedNaleid Lovin' that one-liner =D