# Groovy custom sort

Tags: sorting, grails, groovy

I got a list of employment histories (EH), it's an object. Each EH has date from and date to. User registers application may not in order. How can I sort it by most recent to oldest?

For example:

```
empHistory.each{
  println it.dateFrom +"-"+ it.dateTo
}
```

Result:

```
10/01/2014 - 02/01/2015
03/07/2013 - 07/01/2014
```

Any solution will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reverse the sort of a Groovy collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672811/how-to-reverse-the-sort-of-a-groovy-collection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following piece of code should do the job:

```
empHistory.sort { -it.dateFrom }.each {
   println "$it.dateFrom-$it.dateTo"
}
```